Unbreakable words or \mintinline code overflowing the line when placed as last entity on a line
I keep encountering the problem that a \mintinline expression that ends up at the last entity on a line will overflow the line.
For example, I have this part of my document:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  % *** START OF CODE SNIPPET ***
  \item \mintinline{c++}|PrintDept|: Ausgabe der Abteilung mit dem angegebenen Namen. Dazu wird mit der Hilfsfunktion \mintinline{c++}|FindDeptByName| der Index der Abteilung gesucht und wenn sie gefunden wird, wird sie mithilfe der Funktion \mintinline{c++}|PrintDeptByIndex| in einer übersichtlichen Form ausgegeben. Dann wird \mintinline{c++}|true| zurückgegeben. Wenn die Abteilung nicht gefunden wird, wird \mintinline{c++}|false| zurückgegeben.
  \item \mintinline{c++}|PrintSmallestDept|: Ausgabe der kleinsten Abteilung durch Aufruf der Hilfsfunktion \mintinline{c++}|PrintSmallestOrLargestDept| mit dem Parameter \mintinline{c++}|false|. Wenn die Liste leer ist, wird \mintinline{c++}|false| zurückgegeben, ansonsten \mintinline{c++}|true|.
  \item \mintinline{c++}|PrintLargestDept|: Ausgabe der größten Abteilung durch Aufruf der Hilfsfunktion \mintinline{c++}|PrintSmallestOrLargestDept| mit dem Parameter \mintinline{c++}|true|. Wenn die Liste leer ist, wird \mintinline{c++}|false| zurückgegeben, ansonsten \mintinline{c++}|true|.
  \item \mintinline{c++}|Init|: Initialisierung der Liste. Dazu wird der Platzzähler auf null gesetzt.
  % *** END OF CODE SNIPPET ***
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

It looks like this:

I also tried adding [breaklines] but that did nothing (I didn't expect it to, actually, because I don't want these lines to be broken, it should just not even attempt to place the code at the end of the line and instead use the next line).
At first I thought this is some kind of issue with minted, but it seems it's not, because when I replace the \mintinline{c++}|PrintSmallestOrLargestDept| part with ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ, I get the same behavior:

Why does the code or word not just get placed on the next line?
If I manually add \linebreak before the \mintinline command, it works, but of course this is not great because now I have to keep checking and possibly adjusting those manual line breaks whenever something else changes in those paragraphs:

Is there a better solution?

Have you considered to rephrase the sentence?
